# What is this kind of template mechanism called and how is it useful?

Tags: c++, templates

This makes use of templates for a polymorphic function but when is there an opportunity to specify the `U` template type? I'm not understanding what exactly is going on.

In addition to an explanation, I would like an answer which also includes an applicable use case.

Here is the template example:

```
template<typename T>
class some_class
{
public:
   some_class(const some_class<T>& other) {
   }

   template<typename U>
   some_class(const some_class<U>& other) {
   }
};
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/C8vht2  a demo of @VaughnCato 's answer

Answer (score 2):

The standard library smart pointers are good examples.

(simplified)

```
template <class T>
class unique_ptr
{
public:
    template <class U>
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U>&& u);
};
```

This allows a `unique_ptr` to a derived type (`U`) to be moved into a `unique_ptr` to a base type (`T`).

Answer (score 2):

Function template parameters can be deduced automatically, so there's no need to specify the type of U.

You can write:

```
some_class<float> x(some_class<int>{});
```

and U will automatically be deduced as type `int`.

Comment: You've just declared a function called x (it's C++'s 'most vexing parse').

Comment: @JamesHopkin: Doh! It even vexes me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

A use case

```
  some_class<int> x;       // assuming there is a suitable default constructor
  some_class<float> y(x);
```

Of course, it would normally be expected that the constructors (templated or not) would do something useful, in a way that allows such operations to make sense.

Comment: Wouldn't that make `x` of type `some_class<int>`, which is not accepted by the `<float>` constructor which would only accept `some_class<float>`? It looks more like a way to support `some_class` specializations in the constructor that are not of template type of the "outer" `some_class` instance. So isn't there an `int` missing in your answer? `some_class<float> y<int>(x)`

Comment: I think OP is asking about the conversion constructor.

Comment: @J.. Function template parameters can be deduced automatically.

Comment: J . the conversion from `some_class<int>` to `some_class<float>` will use (an instantiation of) the templated constructor.  There is no `int` missing from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple conversion constructor and doesn't have anything to do with templates. It allows a different type to be converted to the current type. It is very common with smart pointers where a conversion from a derived class can be implicitly converted to the base class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
};

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Derived<T>> createDerived()
{
    return std::make_unique<Derived<T>>();
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base<int>> base = createDerived<int>();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example code the `std::unique_ptr<Derived<int>>` type is auto converted to `std::unique_ptr<Base<int>` thanks to the conversion constructor. Smart pointers try to emulate raw pointers as closely as possible in this is a very useful property.

---

The [`std::unique_ptr` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) shows there is an constructor which allows this conversion.

> (6)
>
> ```
> template< class U, class E >
> unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u );
> ```